# Spring boot : how to change database URL

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Recently I am started learning Spring boot rest API for freelancing work purposes. Recently we bought one hosting server ex:http://105.xx.xx.121/. How to change below data source URL and username and passwords to access that external database.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
```

Comment: You need to know what your database url is, what db engine it uses, schema, username and password. I don't think your question can be answered for lacking information. I would recommend to learn some tutorials out there like https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/datasource-configuration/

Answer (score 0):

Use spring profiles

You can have application.properties or application.yml as environment specific

so create

application-{env}.properties ==>application-prod.properties

Over here you can override the properties, then start spring application with spring profile.

mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments="--spring.profiles.active=prod"